# Error on binding the grid with a list

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

```
List<business.clspluginsprp> objprp = new List<business.clspluginsprp>();
business.clsplugins obj = new business.clsplugins();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{

   Int32 z = Convert.ToInt32(k.GetValue(i));
   objprp.Add(obj.fnd_plugins(z));
}

GridView2.DataSource = objprp;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

An error arrived which is as: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(business.clspluginsprp)' has some invalid arguments while the other error is : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'business.clspluginsprp'

Comment: What is the return type of obj.fnd_plugins(z)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
objprp.Add(obj.fnd_plugins(z));
```

to this:

```
objprp.AddRange(obj.fnd_plugins(z));
```

Since it seems fnd_plugins returns a list in and of itself.  This will also error if fnd_plugins does not return a List generic implementation.  Posting the signature of fnd_plugins will help debug this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fnd_plugins` returns a List of `clsplugins` objects, then you want to use `AddRange` instead of `Add`.  `AddRange` lets you add multiple values in one call.